# How to find if US patent is applicable in INDIA? How to find the PCT number?

Tags: patent-applications, patented

US20160255970A1 has US patent..how to identify if they have applicability in Indian and European Markets? How to find the PCT number?

Answer (score 1):

Patents are territorial. A US patent only provides protection in the United States. US20160255970A1 is a US patent application. The invention was granted as US patent [US9730534B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9730534B2/en?oq=US9730534B2). There are two related US patents by the same inventor [US9930976B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9930976B2/en?oq=US9930976) and [US10206527B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US10206527B2/en?oq=US10206527). I looked in Espacenet and as far as I can see there are no other applications or patents in any other country. You can get to Espacenet by clicking the links provided in the Google Patents page for each patent. Then click the "INPADOC patent family" link. I searched Google Patents for the inventor’s name and there are no non-US publications at all. I'm not an expert in searching India patents so I might have missed something, but it looks like there is no equivalent patents in Europe or India.

I would caution you that I am not a patent lawyer so this isn't legal advice. Also, there is always the possibility of other similar patents by other inventors so a formal freedom to operate analysis is always a good idea.